# Get the rows and display them in echo mysqli prepared

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

im trying to get the rows from database with mysqli prepare statments and display them in echo like `<?php echo $username; ?>` but don't know how to get them , wasted 4 hours no success , help would be greate

php

```
 <?php
 include("secure/functions.php");
 session_start(); 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']); // Bind "$username" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
     if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
     $stmt->bind_result($id,$username); // get variables from result.
       $stmt->fetch();
}
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` loaded? Plus, has `$_SESSION['username']` been assigned anywhere else?

Comment: yup its in top of file, if i type <?php echo $_SESSION['username; ?> anywhere it will give an username of loggedinuser

Comment: Isn't it always? 99% of OP's never post that one bit of important information that leaves us all wondering.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry bro , but the onyl code im trying to work with is this ,,, okay let me edit it with session

Comment: @Fred-ii- done ,,, the all other codes for session are in fucntions.php and working but the only function im trying to make is this which is not working

Comment: Another typo `$session_start();` should be `session_start();` no dollar sign. If that's what you're using, remove it.

Comment: no im not using $ for session_start that was mistaked when i added it now

Comment: How are you assigning a value to `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: If you want to show data, you need to loop through it, either using a `while` or `foreach`

Comment: the error was * in prepared statement :D ,,, its working now

Comment: post your comment as answer let me accept it

Comment: Which one is that? I made many lol

Comment: session and * was the errors :D

Comment: What was the `*` supposed to be, an actual column instead?

Comment: yup look at the bind_results($id,$username) but i haven't indicated them in select

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initially used `$session_start();` where it should be `session_start();` no dollar sign.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check existence of `session_start();` at begin of your script.

And, you can check which value sets to prepared statement - before binding of parameter `$_SESSION['username']`, try to display this value with `echo` or `print`.

Comment: it displays the username when i echo it ,,, but im wondering how to get the rows from table in echo